# Name Correction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

**Name Correction**

As the wedding season is on, John has been given the work of printing guest names on wedding cards. John has written code to print only those names that start with upper-case alphabets and reject those that start with lower-case alphabets or special characters.

**Your job is to do the following:**

1.Correct the rejected names (names which start with lower case or with a special character). You have to change the first alphabet of the rejected name to Upper case and in the case of special character there will be no change.

2.Output the newly corrected names in ascending order.

**Table format**

**Table:   person**

**Field      Type**

name     varchar(20)

## **Sample**

**Sample person table**

**name**

mohit

Kunal

manoj

Raj

tanya

@man

**Sample output table**

 **name**

 @man

 Manoj

 Mohit

 Tanya

***Solution Attempted: IN SQL SERVER 2014***

```
select name
from person as per
where (left(per.name,1) like '%[^A-Z]%' or left(per.name,1) like '% %')
union
select Upper(left(per.name,1))+right(per.name,len(per.name)-1)
from person as per
where left(per.name,1)<>left(Upper(per.name),1) 
collate Latin1_General_CS_AI 
order by per.name
```

**Sample Test Cases Passes,

Still getting wrong answer in some competitor exam.
Please suggest what test case i have not handled.**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Query and expected output looks fine. What is the wrong answer you are getting?

Comment: @Utsav, The output is just a sample, Need to figure out any other test cases that I have not handled. I am getting wrong answer on the hackerearth compiler. Sample test case are passing correctly

Comment: @Zohar suggest me what need to be change in the question that you are not able to understand.

Comment: I'm able to understand the question, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only interested in correcting lower case and reporting special characters in the first character position I would use ascii comparision rather than regex.

```
select name, ascii(left(name,1)),
        case    
            when ascii(left(name,1)) between 97 and 122 then 
            concat(char(ascii(left(name,1)) - 32),substring(name,2,len(name) -1))
        else name
        end  name
from t
where   ascii(left(name,1)) <= 64 or
        ascii(left(name,1)) >= 91
```

Comment: 65 to 90 ascii code belongs to capital A-Z letters. Cool! In fact, your answer is also free from nuances of collation which OP has used in his attempted solution. +1 for letting me know that `concat` function already exists since SQL Server 2012.